# Does IOS app development have minimum/target SDK version similar to Android's

Tags: android, ios

In Android, when building an app you have to specify [minimum SDK version](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html), the lowest Android version that your app will be able to run on.

Is there similar requirement in iOS development where the developer needs to specifically say "The app will run on version 7 and higher" ?

Comment: Yes.  It is in the target settings in Xcode

Comment: you can set 'Deployment target' on your project target.

Comment: Check "Deployment Target".

Comment: For the sake of completeness, it's not exactly the same. Minimum deployment target (SDK) in Android matches the target iOS version in XCode, but Android also has a nice feature which is the actual deployment target which helps selecting the right compiler and toolkit. In XCode you need to update XCode (or be forced to) in order to automatically start compiling with a newer toolkit, sometimes breaking previously working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Xcode project settings :

[image]

Here Deployment target is 8.0 which means minimum supported iOS version is 8.0